# Definir um grupo no regex

Tags: regex

Estou testando a seguinte regex:

```
(?i)(\s|\W|)(fire|fire-type)(\s|\W)
```

Tenho 2 problemas:

1º Caso (RESOLVIDO) tenha apenas uma palavra sem espaços no início ou no fim a minha regex não pega. Ex:

*fire*

2ª No meu grupo tenho um *fire-type* mas a regex pega apenas a palavra *fire* e igonara o *-type*. Alguém sabe como posso resolver estes 2 casos?

Comment: Qual o objetivo da Regex? É localizar em um texto as palavras `fire` e `fire-type`?

Comment: Isso mesmo.... @David

Comment: `(fire\-type)|(fire)` resolve ?

Comment: Responde que eu valido, funcionou...@David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente em expressões regulares o Hífen `-` é um indicador de sequência, por exemplo, ao invés de escrever `[abcdefgh]`, escrevemos, `[a-h]`. Ou se maiúsculas e minusculas com, `[a-hA-H]`.

Dessa forma o Hífen é caractere utilizado para definir sequencias em expressões regulares, se quiser localizar um texto com o hífen devemos avisar ao regex que devem ser entendidos como literal precedendo-os com um sinal de escape `\` (contra-barra), abaixo alguns exemplos comumente utilizados:

```
\- (faz a busca pelo "-")
\] (faz a busca pelo "]")
\\ (faz a busca pelo "\")
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.